# Are there any benefits for exercising with Ivanko Super Gripper in comparison to other hand grippers?

Tags: grip-strength, grip

There are many hand grippers in the market. I would like to know if there is any benefit for using the following Ivanko Super Gripper in comparison to other hand grippers:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-e_kEmvfb4&feature=youtu.be&t=28
Are there also disadvantages for using it?

Answer (score 1):

**Pros**

- Good quality hand grippers tend to be expensive in general, so adjustable grippers are nice for making incremental progress on a budget.
- Adjustable grippers max out ~80-90lbs, which isn't much for anyone with decent forearm strength, while these go much higher.
- The longer frame makes the grip angle on these more natural, as opposed to the 'triangle-grip' that many other grippers offer. You can focus a tad more on just exerting force, and less on having the right form.
- Separate moving parts mean it can be maintained/replaced if it gets worn out. Spring characteristics in grippers do change with use.

**Cons**

- It's larger than many other grippers on the market. Grippers are one of the few travel-friendly pieces of exercise equipment.
- Separate moving parts mean something can break.
- Increasing possibility of causing sonic booms any time you close your hand.